# PHP segurança - evitar SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

É errado ou inseguro usar:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;
   ...
}
```

Digamos que eu tenha esse código, mas use uma chamada de procedure com prepare nas variáveis. Eu corro algum risco de ataque por `Sql Injection`?

**Sendo um pouco mais específico, o meu problema está em:**

> foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;

Eu tenho um relatório de análise e segurança em meu sistema dizendo que isso é uma falha grave de SQL Injection. **Mesmo que eu esteja usando PDO e prepare após isso**!

Comment: Olá @Renan as respostas desse link são boas. Mas eu já executo esses práticas e msm assim meu sistema é vista como veraneável apenas por esse trecho de código mostrado a cima!

Comment: Use `filter_input` e seja feliz!

Comment: Se tem um problema específico, deve postá-lo com detalhes para quem possa ajudá-lo. Assim genérico já foi respondido.

Comment: Use PDO e os prepared statements, e seja feliz (2)

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche infelizmente isso não é suficiente. Pois ja uso PDO e prepared e achava q bastaria isso para estar 100% seguro. Mas descobrir q existe mais coisas com o q se preocupar!

Comment: @alan usa Os prepared statements + filter_input

Comment: usa o filter_input em conjunto, você tem razão eu também achava o suficiente e não é...

Answer (score 0):

Sim, seu método é suscetível a sql injection.

Primeiro alternaria de fazer php em força bruta para ir para um framework tipo Zend Framework ou os mais simples como Codeigniter desta forma você se preocupa mais com o que o seu código deve fazer do que como a segurança deve ser feita.
Bom se queres fazer tudo pelo nativo eu optaria pelo método [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) (INPUT_POST , sua_variável) que é muito mais seguro que o $_post['variável'] ou que seu método afinal ele já verifica se existe e faz alguns filtros para você bem como é possível adicionar opções o tornando bem util, para maiores informações olhe o site do  [php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)  ou o  [link exemplificando como usar ele.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298535/phps-new-input-filter-does-not-read-get-or-post-arrays)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @Gustavo Castro. Mas nesta publicação tinha uma resposta q também recomendava o uso do INPUT_POST. Porém, os outros usuários disseram q isso n resolve o problema e negativaram ela. Com isso o dono da resposta acabou excluindo a mesma!